# Pandas/python Check How many minutes were within an internal

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I calculate in Pandas ,how many minutes are within an interval. For example

```
interval 1: 00:00:00 to 08:00:00
interval 2: 08:00:00 to 24:00:00
```

```
time_start: 06:30:00
time_end:  13:00:00
```

result:

```
interval 1 = 90 minutes
interval 2 = 300 minutes
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're working with [pandas.Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) but hopefully this gives you some inspiration

```
pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp("2020-1-1 00:00:00"), pd.Timestamp("2020-1-1 00:08:00")).length/pd.Timedelta("1 minute")
```

this gives you 8.